# LaTeXiT: Recently lost ability to go from PowerPoint back to LaTeXiT

Tags: latexit, powerpoint, macos

I have been using LaTeXiT for a few years and have many presentations in PowerPoint with embedded equations. About a month ago, I lost the ability to convert equations embedded in a PowerPoint presentation back into LaTeX. I confirmed this happens with any new equations I put into any PowerPoint presentation (old or new). I am trying to copy from PowerPoint and paste into LaTeXiT. I fear that an update from Apple or Microsoft broke something.

PowerPoint for Mac, Version 16.9.1 (180125); LaTeXiT Version 2.8.1; macOS High Sierra, Version 10.13.3

I always paste LaTeX eqns into PowerPoint as PDF. I do not edit any of these equations with the PowerPoint picture tools.

Any ideas?

Comment: LaTeXiT has been at version 2.8.1 for quite a while. Have you changed any preference in LaTeXiT so it isn’t embedding the equation source in the pdf? Can you drag the equation from PowerPoint to the Desktopand get a copy of the pdf?

Comment: I’ve witnessed problems with equations on PowerPoint across versions on OS-X lately too.

Comment: Just in case you haven't tried Keynote I find it works better than PPT. Not everyone will agree of course. But everyone I have seen recently trying Keynote (it's free) has made the switch and not looked back (all your PPT files should open in Keynote if you want to )

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm this problem as well, PowerPoint 16.10 and LaTeXiT 2.9.0.  As a workaround, I can drag from LaTeXiT to desktop (create a pdf file), drag this file to PowerPoint, then drag it back to LaTeXiT.  This preserves embedded equations.  However, directly dragging (or copying) from LaTeXiT into PowerPoints seems to strip off the embedded content.